# React Router 4 and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx, enzyme

Ive switched to react router v4 and few tests need to be reimplemented.
I have following scenario:

- mounting a component (checking if methodA has been called)
- changing the props by enzymes wrapper method: setProps
- checking if method has been called twice

And that was fairly easy with old router.. but it comes very hard with the new one:

If component (or children) contains for example `Link`, it means that we have to provide proper contxt for rendering the component. Thats why `MemoryRouter` has been created:

```jsx
const comp = mount(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Comp {...someProps} />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
//here comes assertion about spy getting called
```

thanks to that we are able to render the component (more info:https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/testing)
But.. if we take a look at `setProps` method at enzyme library (http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/setProps.html):

> A method that sets the props of the root component, and re-renders.

It means that if I call comp.setProps({..newProps}), it actually changes route props (`MemoryRouter`), but doesnt change my component props, which sucks as hell.

Any insights on such case?

Answer (score 7):

You could write wrapper around MemoryRouter and pass all the props down to node that need's to be tested.

```
const CompWrappedWithMemoryRouter = (props) => {
    return (
        <MemoryRouter>
            <Comp {...props />
        </MemoryRouter>
    )
}
```

then use it of course

```
const comp = mount(
      <CompWrappedWithMemoryRouter {...someProps} />
    );
```

now `comp.setProps` should work